# What is the smallest positive number on an 8-segment array? (no repeats)

Tags: open-ended, seven-segment

You are provided with the 8-segment array in the picture together with all the necessary electronics to make any combination of lit segments you want.

[image]

Fillable version for graphics. https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1hnN.png

[image]

What is the **smallest positive number** that you can display without any two boxes being identical?  (A box is a grey rectangle containing 8 segments)

Any combination of segments is allowed within a box provided it is accepted by the community as a valid symbol. ('accepted' is decided by net up-votes for your answer)

Any recognised numbering system that is commonly used is allowed. If the one you use is common but little-known (perhaps because it is specialized) then you must back up your claim with a link to an authoritative source. You must also explain it precisely so that it can be understood by others.

You cannot mix numbering systems unless you can show that this is routinely done by some substantial section of the populace.

You cannot invent your own symbols or language. All symbols must be understandable and approved by the community.

The competition remains open until there has been no answer for one week. At that point (or as soon after as I am able) I shall accept the **most up-voted answer** (net votes).

**Update**

1. The question has been put on hold--therefore I'll make an adjustment about the timescale for accepting an answer  (if you want to reopen it please vote to do so).
2. If I could wind back the clock, I would require the answers to be finite. This was an oversight because I did not think an infinite could be considered a number.
3. Because there are answers and they have been voted on, it is too late to change the criteria. My suggestion is that people who are interested submit answers in the categories of finite or infinite numbers according to their preference. I will stick to my original criterion for acceptance.
   **Note**

You can display your answer using ASCII provided it is clear how it would look when translated into segments. Otherwise please use an actual 8-segment representation to clarify the layout of any symbols that aren't obvious.

Comment: Most upvoted answer is almost certainly not going to be the "correct" answer. Your scoring condition makes this not a puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi, What scoring system do you suggest?

Comment: Smallest valid answer, where validity is determined either by strict rules or, if necessary, positive score.

Comment: It's too late for me to change it now. However, if you have an idea for a similar question but with your rules please feel free to post it.   P.S. My motivation is to find numerical problems that can't be tackled by computer or brute force..

Comment: It's an interesting problem, but "satisfy other people" is what the scoring system essentially boils down to, and the problem itself seems poorly defined.

Answer (score 22):

I don't know if you can get smaller than

> [image]
>
>  **[epsilon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epsilon.html)** - a small positive infinitesimal quantity

Comment: Also possible is: "DEN" for "denormalized number".  Not seen on any calculators that I know of, but I've never seen one that displays "EPSILON" either.  Commonly used in some programming languages to represent a number too small to be programmatically distinguishable from zero, but specifically NOT zero.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman DEN is too short though

Comment: VS C++ (don't know about other languages/compilers) usually shows DEN with a couple of digits after it, so "`DEN0.1234`" maybe?

Answer (score 10):

Here's one to start off:
`1 E - 9 8 7 6 5` $=10^{-98765}$

Comment: You may want to drop the 1 in front of the E, and instead improve the exponent. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687016/what-is-e-in-floating-point.

Comment: @Gamow In my opinion, the E[number] is shorthand for a multiplier, and it's not a well-formed number without something in front of it.

Comment: I am not sure if the order of operations will be executed correctly, but I think this '1E-7^998' (using different ways of representing a 9) will be smaller.

Answer (score 7):

Building up on f'' s answer:

```
        ###           ###    ###    ###    ###    ###
    #  #             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #
    #  #             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #
    #  #             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #
        ###    ###    ###    ###    ###           ###
    #  #                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #
    #  #                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #
    #  #                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #
        ###           ###           ###           ###
```

$=10^{-99876}$

Using the possibility to write the digit 9 in two different ways on this kind of display.

---

Edit:

Dropping the 1 in front we could get as low as  $10^{-998766}$:

```
 ###           ###    ###    ###    ###    ###
#             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #      #
#             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #      #
#             #   #  #   #  #   #      #  #      #
 ###    ###    ###    ###    ###           ###    ###
#                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #  #   #
#                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #  #   #
#                 #      #  #   #      #  #   #  #   #
 ###           ###           ###           ###    ###
```

Comment: As with Gamow's comment to f", you can use this to get E-998765, which I would accept

Comment: I don't think a leading E is widely interpreted as a number. It's certainly not one in C syntax that's widely used as-is or slightly adapted for other languages.

Comment: You could also use an alternative for [7](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Seven_segment_display_7_digit_(green).svg/2000px-Seven_segment_display_7_digit_(green).svg.png).

Answer (score 3):

In non-standard analysis, a halo (or [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(non-standard_analysis))) is described as "the collection hal(x) of numbers which are infinitely close to x " (Lobry et al). Thus, the numbers close to 0 would be hal(0) or monad(0). Hyperreal numbers are described further in "Foundations of Infinitesimal Calculus" (Keisler)

```
       _            _   _      _
| |   | |   |      |   | |      |
|-|   |-|   |      |   | |      |
| |   | |   |_     |_  |_|   . _|
```

References:

Keisler, H. Jerome. *Foundations of infinitesimal calculus*. Vol. 20. Boston: Prindle, Weber & Schmidt, 1976.

Lobry, Claude, and Tewfik Sari. "Non-standard analysis and representation of reality." *International Journal of Control* 81.3 (2008): 519-536.

Comment: This has 2 boxes identical (empty)

Comment: @DrunkWolf fixed

Comment: Is that really a number or is it a set of numbers?

Answer (score 3):

What about

> [image: this].
>  Using Hex, that's A^-FEDCB

Equivalent to 10^-1043915

Comment: I think you need lower-case 'd' or call it zero.

Comment: Also if that is B, then what would 8 be?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

> [image]

Probably not a valid solution though since it is actually not positive.

Comment: That's exactly 0.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote it's not positive. And the more I thought about it after posting it, the sillier it seemed, since it could just as well have said 1-1!

Comment: What about 1 - 0.988...  or  1 - 0.911...   Do all repeating decimal digits round up?

Comment: 1 - 0.988... would be equal to 0.111..., and 1 - 0.9111... would equal 0.088888, they would be positive, but not very small :)

Comment: Lots of duplicate boxes as well in this one

Comment: Wow, you're right, I didn't even think of that. Looks like I completely botched this one! :)

Comment: Without the duplicates rule 1-0.99...9 would have been worth a try (hinting at a really long sequence of 9s that eventually ends).

Answer (score 0):

What about...

> 1 / treE(3)

I think you can do a divide sign...

Comment: Can you show how this can be done with the LEDs?

Comment: center, top right, and bottom left segment could be a passable slash. Not sure what `t` looks like, though.

Comment: Top-left, center, bottom-left and bottom