# What is the largest possible positive number on an 8-segment array? (repeated symbols allowed)

Tags: open-ended, seven-segment

This is a follow-up to the question, [What is the smallest possible positive number on an 8-segment array?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23656/what-is-the-smallest-positive-number-on-an-8-segment-array)  However, this time repeats are allowed!

You are provided with the 8-segment array in the picture together with all the necessary electronics to make any combination of lit segments you want.

[image]

Fillable version for graphics https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1hnN.png

[image]

What is the largest positive number that you can display? Unlike in the previous question, boxes can be identical. (A box is a grey rectangle containing 8 segments)

Any combination of segments is allowed within a box provided it is accepted by the community as a valid symbol. ('accepted' is decided by net up-votes for your answer)

Any recognised numbering system that is commonly used is allowed. If the one you use is common but little-known (perhaps because it is specialized) then you must back up your claim with a link to an authoritative source. You must also explain it precisely so that it can be understood by others.

You cannot mix numbering systems unless you can show that this is routinely done by some substantial section of the populace.

You cannot invent your own symbols or language. All symbols must be understandable and approved by the community.

The competition remains open until there has been no answer for one week. At that point (or as soon after as I am able) I shall accept the most up-voted answer (net votes).

**Update**

1. If the question gets closed (and then possibly reopened) then I'll make an adjustment about the timescale for accepting an answer.
2. If I could wind back the clock, I would require the answers to be finite. This was an oversight because I did not think an infinite could be considered a number.
3. Because there are answers and they have been voted on, it is too late to change the criteria. My suggestion is that people who are interested submit answers in the categories of finite or infinite numbers according to their preference. I will stick to my original criterion for acceptance.

Note

You can display your answer using ASCII text provided it is clear how it would look when translated into segments. Otherwise please use an actual 8-segment representation to clarify the layout of any symbols that aren't obvious.

Comment: Most upvoted answer is almost certainly not going to be the "correct" answer. Your scoring condition makes this not a puzzle.

Comment: Here is a definition of puzzle. "*b :  a question, problem, or contrivance designed for testing ingenuity*" http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puzzle  -- I think I have complied with that.

Comment: Because of the upvote metric, this question just tests how well you can get other people to upvote you. It may test ingenuity, but I don't think it's a puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi, In that case I define this to be an open-ended puzzle that tests people's ingenuity in getting up-votes. The medium for doing this is a mathematical one.

Comment: By that definition nearly everything is a puzzle. Is poker a test of ingenuity in getting people to believe you have a good hand? Is an exam a test of ingenuity of guessing what the teacher wants you to respond? You could technically say yes, but that doesn't make them puzzles.

Answer (score 4):

If we're restricted to finite numbers, I submit...

[image]

ggggggg9.

That's the (((((((9th number in Graham's series)th number in Graham's series)th number in Graham's series)...)))) where Graham's series (notated as gn for some n) is defined under "definition" [here.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)

Comment: That's quite big.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Yep. No idea why this was upvoted but aleph-999 wasn't though.

Comment: Maybe because this is finite?

Comment: You could make it a little bigger by using two single segments in the last box to make an 11.

Comment: Is this number bigger or mine [tree(99)]? I don't know enough maths to figure it out.

Comment: @ghosts: I have no idea!  I think mine is bigger. Not quite sure though - I don't really understand the TREE function.

Answer (score 4):

Using actual digits (instead of letters or concepts), I present

[image]

or $9^{11111111111111}$

Comment: That reminds me of $9 \times 60^{-14}$. Since $9'$ is $9/60$ (9 minutes), $9''$ is $9/3600$ (9 seconds), etc.

Comment: i.e. the number is $9''''''''''''''$.

Answer (score 3):

I submit

[image]

ALEPH 999.

It's infinite, 998 'steps' above countable infinity.

Comment: Hmm... Is that a number though? I don't think it is. Maybe I should have specified 'finite'.  Let's see what the voting says.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Yes, it is. It's part of the cardinal number system.

Comment: I think I need convincing. Can you show me a link where it is defined as a 'number'?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number

Comment: Darn it. Let's see if anyone can beat it. (And there was me thinking a googol was big!)

Comment: Oh, a googol's TINY! Have you heard of Graham's number? Even though it's finite, it's so huge that we can't comprehend how many digits it has. Or how many digits THAT number has. Or how many THAT number has...

Comment: Yes but can you write Graham's number on an 8-segment display? How will you do the 'm'?

Comment: I was thinking about just "infinity", but in math that's not considered a number.

Comment: @Dennis_E, Even if it was, How would you show 'infinity' on the display?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK http://i.imgur.com/i0rY863.png or something like that

Comment: @Dennis_E: This is an infinity.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: Graham's number is notated with just a lowercase g. ;)

Comment: @Deusovi I know. That's why I mentioned it.

Comment: @Dennis_E, Yes, that looks good.

Comment: "ALEPHG64" is another solution that sort of works.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

TREE(99) from Kruskal's tree theorem.

Answer (score 1):

As someone has submitted an infinite number, I'll kick off with a finite one which is pretty big.

1 GOOGOL

[image]

P.S. I'd also offer 9 GOOGOL  but I don't know if I would need an 'S' on the end.

EDIT

Or 99GOOGOL if I am allowed to omit the space.

Comment: The quotes arouns "number" are unnecessary.

Comment: You don't need an S at the end c:

Comment: Do I need a space between the digit and the G?

Comment: I think it's okay to not have that space for a 7-seg display.

Comment: 9eGOOGOL maybe?

Comment: @Dennis_E: I think you'd need to say "1 googol", not just "googol".